# detect if given Email ID is configured in Mail?

Tags: iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am creating a mail app. I am using MFMailComposeViewController. I am able to check whether the mail client is configured with any of email or not. But can I check that the mail client is configured by a particular email account.

I want to force user to first setup his mail account and then try to send mail. For that I need to check if user is trying to send mail from abc@gmail.com then it should be configured so is it possible to check that if iphone's Mail app is configured by given email.

If possible then how and if not then any alternatives..

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API doesn't expose that information publicly (for probably good reasons, such as preventing developers from harvesting iPhone users' email addresses).